# How do I send a user-inputted date to Hibernate + SQL db JSF 2.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to send a date via JSF 2.0 and hibernate to one of my SQL DB fields. Hibernate automatically reverse engineered the field and mapped it to a date() object, but I'm now not sure how to parse a user-inputted string in the correct format to set to a date() object, and then to my DB.

Comment: Are you using plain JSF or another library like PrimeFaces or RichFaces?

Comment: just the JSF 2.0 libs that come with MyEclipse 10

Comment: You should handle the input as a String, then use [SimpleDateFormat#parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to create a Date from the String.

Comment: that didn't work, it caused some problems with the date property because this way you'd have to set it with a string, then in the setter parse it to a date

Comment: I didn't fully undertand your problem, that's why I suggested using the SimpleDateFormat, I've upvoted baraber answer.

Comment: no biggie, just letting you know. I appreciate the help either way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jsf date converter :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      >
...
    <h:inputText id="date" value="#{yourBean.dateField}" 
                 size="20" required="true">

        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
    </h:inputText>
...
</html>
```

And in your JSF bean :

```
Date dateField;

public Date getDateField() {
  return date;
}

public void setDateField(Date date) {
  this.date = date;
}
```

And the JPA mapping :

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) java.util.Date date;
```

Comment: thank you! I'm not quite sure what's going on with the last part but it worked without the JPA mapping.